# Android View.isShown() is returning false when the View is showing

Tags: android, view, visibility

I have a `TextView` named `tvCallToActionBanner` that is shown depending on certain events. This method below controls whether said `TextView` gets shown. This method gets called in the `Activity's onResume()` and a couple of other methods call it as well.

```
public void showCallToActionBanner() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (!mPrefs.getCurrentLiveGameDateId().isEmpty()) {
                mPrefs.setCallToActionType(GlobalVars.CTA_IN_GAME);
                tvCallToActionBanner.setText(R.string.cta_game_in_progress);
                if (!tvCallToActionBanner.isShown()) showCallToActionBanner(true);
            }
            else if (mPrefs.getLiveGameDateStatus().equals(GlobalVars.LIVE_GAME_DATE_SEARCHING)) {
                mPrefs.setCallToActionType(GlobalVars.CTA_LIVE_GAME_DATE_SEARCHING);
                tvCallToActionBanner.setText(R.string.cta_live_game_date_searching);
                if (!tvCallToActionBanner.isShown()) showCallToActionBanner(true);
            }
            else if (!mPrefs.getUnratedGameDateIds().isEmpty()) {
                mPrefs.setCallToActionType(GlobalVars.CTA_RATE_MATCH);
                mPrefs.setCallToActionId(mPrefs.getUnratedGameDateIds().iterator().next());
                tvCallToActionBanner.setText(R.string.cta_unrated_match);
                if (!tvCallToActionBanner.isShown()) showCallToActionBanner(true);
            }
            else if (tvCallToActionBanner.isShown()) {
                showCallToActionBanner(false);
            }
        }
    });
}

public void showCallToActionBanner(final boolean shouldShow) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (shouldShow) {
                Animation enterAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim
                        .banner_slide_down);
                enterAnim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                        int paddingTop = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen
                                .main_container_top_spacing_for_banner);
                        mainContainer.setPadding(0, paddingTop, 0, 0);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                    }
                });

                tvCallToActionBanner.startAnimation(enterAnim);
                tvCallToActionBanner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else {
                Animation exitAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim
                        .banner_slide_up);
                exitAnim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                        mainContainer.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                    }
                });

                tvCallToActionBanner.startAnimation(exitAnim);
                tvCallToActionBanner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

So when I trigger the `tvCallToActionBanner` to show in Activity A, it shows with no issues.

I create Activity B, and the `onResume()` gets called and it shows it with no problems.

And then I create Activity C, `onResume()` gets called and shows `tvCallToActionBanner`. I call a method which now hides `tvCallToActionBanner` and it hides with no issues.

I press the back button and it goes back to Activity B, which calls the `onResume()` and should be hiding the `tvCallToActionBanner` but it isn't.

I checked the `tvCallToActionBanner.isShown()` and it is returning false in Activity B after I press the back button from C. But the view is clearly showing and should be returning `true`.

**Is it because the way the order of the `Views` are drawn? I have tried to move the method call to `onPostResume()` but that did nothing. How do I get the `tvCallToActionBanner.isShown()` to return true when it is showing?**

Comment: why you won't use a `View.getVisibility` method?

Comment: @Jakombo This is working now! Please add an answer so I can accept it! I was under the intention that `View.isShown()` returns the `visibility` of the View and all it's sub-views...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a [View.getVisibility()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getVisibility()) method.

```
if(textView.getVisibility == View.VISIBLE) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

isShown() checks also the visibility of its ancestors - so the view itself could be visible but one of its parents isn't (@see [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#isShown()))

Answer (score 0):

```
    textview.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener {
        Toast.makeText(this,"layout changed "
                +textview.isShown
            ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show()

        Toast.makeText(this,"visible "+
                (textView.visibility==View.VISIBLE)
            ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show()

    }
```